# How do you complete the arrow puzzle in Hotland?

Tags: undertale

I've been trying to do the Arrow Jump puzzle in the hotland but I can't figure out how to complete it. How do I complete this puzzle?

[image: The Puzzle]

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings, it would be a good idea to post a screenshot of that puzzle, or at least explain where you encountered it.

Comment: This is the second question you've asked with very little detail of effort put into it. You'll get more and better answers if you include more detail in your questions.

Comment: You can simply look this up and find multiple videos and tutorials with the solution. Did you do any research?

Comment: To those voting to close: this is technically on-topic. It is clear what the question is and it has enough detail. However, it does not show any research effort and is not useful. I would recommend casting a downvote instead of a close vote.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the arrow puzzle you're talking about is the one where you're launched between multiple platforms, here's a simple step-by-step solution.

1. Start on the right-hand side - ensure that the platform immediately left of the launchpad on the right-hand side has *down* and *left* open:
   [image: like this.]
2. Toggle the button on the right, then launch off the launchpad.
3. Launch downward twice, then back up once.
4. Launch back down, left, then up.
5. Launch up.
6. Launch left.

Assuming you've done this correctly, the puzzle should now have been completed.

Comment: I still don't know what to do, Can you do the arrow signs?